# Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W simultaneous AP and client

Tags: wifi, hotspot, wireless-adapter, hostapd, pi-zero-w-2

I have seen many tutorials on using a Raspberry Pi Zero W as a simultaneous WiFi AP and client such as [this one on Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2017/09/29/simultaneous-ap-client-on-the-pi-zero-w/) and [this blog post](https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/), but these tutorials don't seem to work on the Raspberry Pi Zero **2** W.

Can this be achieved? If so, how?

To be clear, I am not looking for a solution for a specific error, but rather an alternate method that will work with the Raspberry Pi Zero **2** W.

Comment: What doesn't work? No one can help if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @ChadG There is no specific error message I need to fix. I want to find a method to use the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W's inbuilt WiFi chip as both a WiFi AP and client simultaneously.

Comment: Well how do you know they wont work then?

Comment: @ChadG Because the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W does _not_ connect to the configured network and spawn its own. This makes it clear that _something_ has not worked. I have seen many people say the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W has too many hardware differences from the Raspberry Pi Zero W for the same methods to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer. [RaspAP](https://raspap.com) has an option called [AP-STA](https://docs.raspap.com/ap-sta/) which allows for this. Confirmed working on my Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.